# Python: linecache.getline not working as intended

Tags: python, file, linecache

I have a directory with numerous subdirectories.

At the bottom of the directories there are some .txt files i need to extract line 2 from.

```
import os
import os.path
import linecache

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk("."):
    for filename in [f for f in filenames if f.endswith(".txt")]:
        #print os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
        #print filename
        print linecache.getline(filename, 2)
```

I am able to successfully parse all the directories and find every text file.  But linecache.getline simply returns newline (where there should be data from that line of the files).  Using

```
print linecache.getline(filename, 2).rstrip('\n')
```

Does not solve this either.

I am able to correctly print out just the filenames in each directory, but passing these to linecache seems to potentially be the issue.  I am able to use `linecache.getline(file, lineno.)` successfully if I just run the script on 1 .txt file in the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

linecache.getline takes filename from current working directory.

Solution is thus:

```
import os
import os.path
import linecache

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk("."):
    for filename in [f for f in filenames if f.endswith(".txt")]:
        direc = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
        print linecache.getline(direc, 2)
```